# Which method is preferred in hibernate to perform MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria, querydsl

I am newbie to hibernate. I have come across several tutorials. But, that tutorials are not clearing my doubts. So, I would like to know the answers for several questions that I have.

1. What is the difference between Hibernate and Hibernate JPA?
2. What is Creteria queries, QueryDSL API? Why we need these APIs in our application? Can we use these APIs together?
3. What is query method? How to use Query methods in our application?
4. I have seen in many places that some persons are using the below code to save the data into database

   ```
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Product p=new Product();
    p.setProductId(101);
    p.setProName("iPhone");
    p.setPrice(25000);

    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(p);
    tx.commit();
   ```

But, some persons are using the below code to access the database,

```
public interface ProductRepository extends BaseModelRepository<Product,Integer>
{
  @Query("SELECT e FROM #{#entityName} e WHERE product_id = :productId")
  public Iterable<Product> findByProductId(@Param("productdId") int productId);
}
```

Which method is preferrable to access the MySQL database? Please, make me clear.